# Error when creating new channel: Unknown field ChannelField.group_id

Tags: channel, error, database-error

I have this nagging issue on a site and I can't track down the cause..

When I attempt to create a new channel, I get: Unknown field ChannelField.group_id

This site has been updated over time and never got an error while updating.. now it's at 5.3.1.

I have compared the tables with a fresh install and cant find any missing fields...

Anyone else had this?

```
ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Select.php:776

Stack Trace: Please include when reporting this error

#0 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Select.php(633): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Select->translateProperty('group_id')
#1 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Select.php(620): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Select->applyFilter(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Database\Query), Array)
#2 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Select.php(116): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Select->applyFilters(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Database\Query), Array)
#3 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Select.php(48): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Select->buildQuery()
#4 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/DataStore.php(282): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Select->run()
#5 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/DataStore.php(228): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\DataStore->runQuery('Select', Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder))
#6 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Builder.php(144): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\DataStore->selectQuery(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder))
#7 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Builder.php(63): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder->fetch()
#8 user/addons/calendar/ft.calendar.php(494): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder->all()
#9 ee/legacy/libraries/api/Api_channel_fields.php(410): Calendar_ft->display_settings(Array)
#10 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/FieldFacade.php(226): Api_channel_fields->apply('display_setting...', Array)
#11 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/FieldModel.php(72): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\FieldFacade->getSettingsForm()
#12 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Channels/Channels.php(320): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\FieldModel->getSettingsForm()
#13 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Channels/Channels.php(166): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Channels\Channels->form()
#14 [internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Channels\Channels->create()
#15 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(241): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(110): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array)
#17 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php(151): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Request))
#18 html/beheer.php(157): require_once('...')
#18 html/beheer.php(157): require_once('...')
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I had this issue on a site recently.  Couldn't create or update channels or fields.  Turns out it was the Solspace Calendar module.  Uninstalling it fixed the error, bit obviously deleted all the content.